# Entity Framework Entries to Static IEnumerable

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm creating a method to log Entity Framework Entries separating entries in IEnumerables to use then after SaveChanges().

The problem is on the Entries that were Deleted, after the call of the SaveChanges(), the Entity Framework, changes my list updating the Deleted entries with the new Properties, and loosing old ones. How can I save the entries to any kind of static list that will not change after the SaveChanges()?

```
var entries = context.ChangeTracker.Entries();
var deletedRecords = entries.Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Deleted).toList();

context.SaveChanges();

//Entries loose OriginalValues and State is updated to Detached
```

Comment: deattach them from the context, deep copy, or if your just using the for logging do the logging in a transaction first

Comment: @johnny5 I will try this out! Thanks!